# What are the Bidirectional methodoly based pre-trained models in NLP

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, data-science-model, transformer

BERT model is useful to solve many NLP tasks (11+) like Sentiment analysis, Q&A, summarization and NER.

what are the other predefined model similar to BERT?
what is best way to find them in NLP?

Comment: I think this question is too broad, because there are dozens of models. Only filtering by "bert" among Huggingface models, [we obtain 14k matches](https://huggingface.co/models?sort=downloads&search=bert).

Comment: sorry for question forming. have edited question. please refer now.. @noe